# javascript - adding a div inside an element received by getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Im really beginner to this so sorry if this question is very basic.
I have a button with background-image and I want to insert a small little icon inside the button to appear on its backgound-image.

Now, I'm getting the button element this way:

```
elements = document.getElementsByClassName("test");
var div = document.createElement("innerdiv");
div="";
var element = elements[0];
```

I think all I need to do is insert a div inside the button div
but how can I do this from here?

Comment: Please post your code so we can help. A tip, `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList. Check here for more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM

Comment: I can only use getelement by class because the button have only class

Comment: Have you tried using CSS pseudo elements?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
    // getElementsByClassName returns a list, so we'll take the first value
    var firstMatch = document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0];

    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    // (Here is where you would set the id & attributes of the new div)
    firstMatch.appendChild(newDiv);
```

Comment: The OP is trying to insert an img element in a button. Inserting a div is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<div class="button" id="button1"></div>
```

javascript:

```
function addIcon(id) {
  var btn = document.getElementById(id);
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.style.className = 'icon';
  btn.appendChild(div);
}
addIcon('button1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a div as a child of a button element, it's invalid HTML. Browsers will either throw an error or probably put the div after the button.

A button can have multiple IMG elements as children and you can use CSS to put one image on top of another (say positioned in the top left). e.g.

```
<button  style="position: relative;" class="test">
  <img src="b.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="a.gif" alt="" style="position: absolute; left:0; top: 0;">
</button>
```

To do the above, and assuming there is an image in the button already, you can do something like:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'a.jpg';
img.alt = 'icon';
img.className = 'buttonIcon';
elements[0].appendChild(img);
```

And you need a bit of CSS support:

```
.test {
  /* In addition to current rules, if any */
  position: relative;
}

/* make the icon sit in the top left corner */
.buttonIcon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

You could apply the CSS hard coded in script, but better to use rules I think.